# how to configuration Spring Spark Cassandra with xml?

Tags: spring, apache-spark, cassandra

I am trying to build a arima-time-series analysis using apache spark mllib with cassandra in spring framework.
Now I want configure spark with cassandra in spring with web.xml. 
I want to configure spark-cassandra-spring configuration with xml.
I have already researched for java configuration now I want to configure in XML format . Please help me for the solutions.
Thanks in advance.

```
    @Configuration
    public class SparkCassandraConfig {
        @Value("${spark.master}")
        String sparkMasterUrl;
        @Value("${cassandra.host}")
        String cassandraHost;
        @Value("${cassandra.keyspace}")
        String cassandraKeyspace;

        @Bean
        public JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext() {
            SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true)
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraHost)
    //                .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")
    //                .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")
                .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "client");

            JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(sparkMasterUrl, "SparkDemo", conf);
            return context;
        }

        @Bean
        public CassandraSQLContext sqlContext() {
            CassandraSQLContext cassandraSQLContext = new 
             CassandraSQLContext(javaSparkContext().sc());
            cassandraSQLContext.setKeyspace(cassandraKeyspace);
            return cassandraSQLContext;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your question, how to translate the above java-script code to xml?

Comment: It is a java code , and my question how to translate the above java code to xml?